# Flickr Authentication Flow and iPhone

Tags: iphone, authentication, redirect, flickr, cfbundleidentifier

I'm attempting to hook my application into Flickr but having issues during the Authentication process.

I've followed:

http://code.flickr.com/blog/2009/11/19/building-authorized-flickr-apps-for-the-iphone/

and

https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr

I've create a CFBundleURLTypes for my application (let's call it myapp://) and tested that it works (i.e. I type myapp:// in Mobile Safari and my application launches). I've successfully called the authentication URL in Flickr, it shows the login, asks the user to grant my app the necessary permissions then instead of redirecting back to my app via my URL gives me:

> Page not found. Sorry :(

Under Flickr's Authentication Flow for the application I set it to: "Web Application" and the URL as myapp://auth?

However, it appears (it happens quickly so hard to know for sure) that instead of redirecting to myapp://auth?[with Frob data] it instead goes to http://m.flickr.com/#/myapp://auth?[Frob data]

Not sure what I did incorrectly.

**EDIT**: I copied the URL string from the Debugger and ran it on the desktop. When doing it through the desktop, it redirected properly (attempting to launch a non-existing app). So, it appears to only be an issue on Mobile Safari?

Comment: It's working for me without problems (using ObjectiveFlickr). My callback URL looks like this: myapp://flickrauth (no question mark).

Comment: Ok, figured it out. My custome bundle scheme started with a number, which apparently is not a good idea. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the custom scheme started with a number rather than alpha. Changing the scheme to be pure alpha fixed the issue.