# ios flickr api: Flickr callback URL not being called

Tags: ios, iphone, oauth, flickr

I'm attempting to hook my application into Flickr but having issues during the Authentication process.

I've followed instructions in:

https://github.com/devedup/FlickrKit

I've created a CFBundleURLTypes for my application (let's call it myapp://) and tested that it works (i.e. I type myapp:// in a safari). I've successfully called the authentication URL in Flickr, it shows the login, asks the user to grant my app the necessary permissions then instead of redirecting back to my app via my URL...it does nothing, and the app is not authenticated.

I used FlickrKit demo app replacing its api key/secret/CFbundleUrltypes with mines and the issue is the same, so the problem is not in the code but rather in the way i registered my app in flickr. Said that...I just followed the instructions in Flickr "Edit Authentication Flow" so I guess the issue is with the callback url I put in flickr. I used myapp://auth? as described in many posts in the internet but does not authenticate or call back my app.

This is not the same issue reported here:

[Flickr Authentication Flow and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455403/flickr-authentication-flow-and-iphone)

but rather similar to the unanswered post:

[flickr callback URL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704880/flickr-callback-url-not-working)

The Info.plist for the custom URL handler and the AppDelegate code are a copy&paste from the flickrKit demo app [no need to reinvent the wheel] and anyway even after changing api key secret and url in flickrKit demo app with mines...the app is not called back, so it must be something wrong in my app registration.

Anybody experienced a similar behavior ? i ruled out objective-c code and callback url as the issue, so what is left is the flickr part but not sure where to look for help... so i wrote this post.

Thanks for any tip,
       dom

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is a problem of api signature calculation. All the parameters passed via method should be used to calculate an api signature.

Comment: Thanks but not sure what do you mean with api signature calculation. My sample project is almost an exact copy of Flickkitdemo except for the app to callback (mine).

Comment: api signature is calculated using a specific method using the api key and parameters passed with the flickr api method called.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this... I am seeing the exact same problem